# How to find next item for a numeric order with dot hierarchy order in string in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

My problem is the following. I have an application that contains activities to execute in a specific order, but each one can contain subactivities recursively. Those activities are stored in a SQL server 2012 database.

At first my table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Actividad]
(
[ID] SMALLINT IDENTITY(50,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
[Nombre] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
[Descripcion] NVARCHAR(120) NULL, 
[EsRequerido] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,  
[Dependencia] SMALLINT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [FK_Actividad_Actividad] FOREIGN KEY ([Dependencia]) REFERENCES [Actividad]([ID]),
)
```

Where `[Dependencia]` references the previous activity.

Then the client wants the activities to have a hierarchy, so I added a column parent `[ActividadPadre]`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Actividad]
(
[ID] SMALLINT IDENTITY(50,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
[Nombre] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
[Descripcion] NVARCHAR(120) NULL, 
[EsRequerido] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,  
[Dependencia] SMALLINT NULL, 
[ActividadPadre] SMALLINT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [FK_Actividad_Actividad] FOREIGN KEY ([Dependencia]) REFERENCES [Actividad]([ID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Actividad_Actividad_2] FOREIGN KEY ([ActividadPadre]) REFERENCES [Actividad]([ID]), 
)
```

But it becomes more complicated to validate what the next activity is.
So I thought to change `[Dependencia]` and `[ActividadPadre]` to a column named `[OrdenJeraquico]` (hierarchy order) which can contain the hierarchy in a string like '1.2.1'.

The rule for a given number:

- if it contains children, get immediate children
- if not children, get all sibilings
- otherwise get next uncle in numerical order.

For example, table contains:

```
1.1
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.2
1.2.1
1.2.1.1
2.1
2.2
2.4
4.1
3.1
1.2.2;
```

So, if i give `1.1` the result must be `1.1.1` and `1.1.2;`

- 1.1.2 -> 1.2
- 1.2 -> 1.2.1, 1.2.2
- 1.2.1 -> 1.2.1.1
- 2.2 -> 2.4
- 3.1 -> 4.1 and so on.

My first aproach requires 3 functions: 1 `getChildren()`, 2 `getSibilings()`, `getParent()` or `getUncle()`.

For children:

```
DECLARE @actual NVARCHAR(20) = '1.1'
SELECT  [OrdenJerarquico]
FROM ....
WHERE [OrdenJerarquico] LIKE CONCAT(@actual, '%') AND P.OrdenJerarquico <> @actual
```

That returns `1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.4, ....`

For Sibilings this is the same function, except that it removes the last digit and removes children from the result:

```
DECLARE @actual NVARCHAR(20) = '1.'
SELECT  [OrdenJerarquico]
FROM ....
WHERE [OrdenJerarquico] LIKE CONCAT(@actual, '%') AND P.OrdenJerarquico <> @actual
```

That returns `1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 1.8, .....`

And for the parent/uncle I have no idea. I thought split by dot and cast to integer, then select where greater than my split number. But the column is string not int, and I cannot have columns for each part (major, minor) because the activities may or may not contain subactivities. Other ativities can be added later. Almost any activity is optional, so if the user selects `1.2.4.1` it must select `1.2.4` and `1.2`, but can select `1.2, 1.2.4` only.

I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: So the 'next' activity would be ... If this activity has children, then the first child, else if this activity has one which is dependent upon it (a sibling) then the sibling, else if the parent has an activity which is dependent upon it (an uncle) then the uncle, else this is the last step. (?)

Comment: if this activity has children, then all the children.
if children activityes are completed or not children then the first sibiling.
if all sibilings are completed, then next activity wich is sibiling of the parent.

Comment: Have you looked at using [hierarchyid (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

This query will return each activity along with the one which should be next:

```
Select ID,
    Nombre,
    Descripcion,
    EsRequerido,
    Dependencia,
    ActividadPadre,
    NextActividad = Coalesce(ChildActividad.ID, SiblingActividad.ID, UncleActividad.ID)
  From Actividad
  Left Join (Select * From Actividad Where Dependencia Is Null) As ChildActividad On Actividad.ID = ChildActividad.ActividadPadre
  Left Join Actividad As SiblingActividad On Actividad.ID = SiblingActividad.Dependencia
  Left Join Actividad As UncleActividad On Actividad.ActividadPadre = UncleActividad.Dependencia;
```

The next activity is determined as follows:

1. If there is an item with this activity as a parent, which does not have a dependency
2. If there is an item for which this is a dependency
3. If there is an item for which the parent of this item is a dependency